# No implicit conversion of symbol to integer for Sinatra file upload

Tags: ruby, file-upload, sinatra

I'm trying to use Sinatra to upload a file and save it in a local directory (which will be a web server later) and I keep getting the error `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` on line 14.

It's not until line 23 that I try to convert to an integer.

```
require 'sinatra'

ssimages = []

get '/login' do
  erb :login, :locals => {}
end

get '/upload' do
  erb :upload, :locals =>{:message => "Please Enter all the required information."}
end

post '/upload' do
  filename = params[:file][:filename]
  tempfile = params[:file][:tempfile]
  path = "./public/img/ss/#{filename}"
  File.open(path, 'wb') do |f|
    f.write(tempfile.read)
  end

  selection = []

  position = params[:location].to_i
  caption = params[:caption]

  selection[0] = path
  selection[1] = caption

  ssimages[position] = selection

  erb :current_csv, :locals => {:message => "", :ssimages => ssimages}
end
```

Here is the form:

```
<form action="/upload" method="POST">
      <label for="position">Where in the slideshow do you want the image?</label>
      <select id="position" name="position">
        <option value="1">Position 1</option>
        <option value="2">Position 2</option>
        <option value="3">Position 3</option>
        <option value="4">Position 4</option>
        <option value="5">Position 5</option>
      </select>
      <label for="file">Select file to upload:</label>
      <input type="file" id="file" name="file" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="caption">Type a caption for the image:</label>
      <textarea id="caption" name="caption" required></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Information">
    </form>
```

Comment: You have some very dangerous code in `post '/upload'`. Don't let a user specify where a file can be written on your system. In particular `"./public/img/ss/#{filename}"` could be used to write to files outside your web-space if someone passed in something like `../../../etc/passwd`. Take advantage of `File.realpath` and `File.absolute_path` to sniff out where they're actually specifying, or better, use `File.basename` to only allow the name of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your responses everybody!  I finally figured out that if I put the: 
`enctype="multipart/form-data"`

in the form tag instead of the input tag it will work.

I did this file upload this way based on several "Sanatra file upload" tutorials that I found on the web.  I'm still new at this so I appreciate everyone's suggestions.  If anyone has an opinion on a better way to handle file uploads I will be happy to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates that you are attempting to access an `Array` or `String` as though it were a `Hash`. This happens because `Hash` access, `Array` access, and `String` access are all done using the `[]` operator. `Array` and `String` access only allow integers (e.g. `ary[1]`), whereas `Hash` access allows any object as a key (though most often we use symbols, e.g. `hash[:foo]`).

To avoid this error, you need to make sure that each time you use the access operator `[]` you know exactly what the object is you are working with.

My guess is that `params` or `params[:file]` is not actually a `Hash`.

Comment: `params` is a hash, so `params[:file]` would work, but the secondary hash-of-hash would usually fail.

Answer (score 1):

I stripped your code down to the bare minimum, and here's what I see happening:

```
require 'json'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  '<html><body>
    <form action="/upload" method="POST">
        <label for="position">Where in the slideshow do you want the image?</label>
        <select id="position" name="position">
          <option value="1">Position 1</option>
          <option value="2">Position 2</option>
          <option value="3">Position 3</option>
          <option value="4">Position 4</option>
          <option value="5">Position 5</option>
        </select>
        <label for="file">Select file to upload:</label>
        <input type="file" id="file" name="file" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="caption">Type a caption for the image:</label>
        <textarea id="caption" name="caption" required></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Information">
      </form>
  </body></html>'

end

post '/upload' do
  params.to_s
end
```

Running that and filling in values returns:

```
{"position"=>"1", "file"=>"test.rb", "caption"=>"image caption", "submit"=>"Submit Information"}
```

That hash has no sub-hashes, which means you're getting nils when you try to access sub-hashes. That's going to be a problem:

```
filename = params['file']['filename'] # => nil
"./public/img/ss/#{filename}" # => "./public/img/ss/"
```

If `path = "./public/img/ss/#{filename}"` results in `"./public/img/ss/"` then

```
File.open(path, 'wb')
  f.write(tempfile.read)
```

are going to fail very badly.

At this point I see no way your form and code could work together.